# Data overriding the given limits in a MySql Table

Tags: mysql

I have created this table:

```
create table t(amount int(5));
```

and I have tried to insert these values:

```
insert into t values
  (1),
  (11),
  (111),
  (1111),
  (11111),
  (111111),
  (11111111);
```

Why does the table accepts all the above values instead of the giving ERROR ?
Is there any solution for this problem ?

Comment: what does a select * show you?

Comment: `int(5)` doesn't mean the number of digits is limited to 5. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: int 5 doesn't mean number of digits that you can insert into the row. What do you want to do? do you want to limit the number of digits to 5?

Comment: @bonCodigo YES I want to limit the number of digits to 5

Comment: @scones SELECT * from t : show all these Inserted values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Int is always four bytes wide.

In the case of int(5) means `display-width` is 5

To see its working use following query to create table

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
    `amount` INT(5) ZEROFILL NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

and insert number 20 .

Then if you try to run `select * from t` you will get following

[image]